# создал бота в вк на botact express.js

Tags: vkontakte-api

написал пару функций чтобы бот отвечал на некоторые сообщения типа:

```
bot.command('привет', ({ reply }) => {
    reply('Привет, как дела?')
})




// User wrote any message
bot.on(({ reply }) => {
  reply('What?')
})
```

вставил эту функцию чтобы бот отвечал на все сообщения но не выполняется.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/botact по этому сайту я делал бота

Answer (score 1):

все проблема решена я убрал старый код и вставил

```
bot.on(({ reply }) => {
  reply('What?')
})
```

теперь работает